# using APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP to determine Read Only vs Edit

Tags: oracle-apex

I have an application written in Oracle Apex 4.2
Different users have access to different pages. Apex's built in Access Control function ( `ADMIN, EDIT, VIEW`) takes care of what pages different users can see.
A separate requirement though is that some users can see certain pages and not edit them and other users can edit those pages.
I know that at the item level there is a Read Only option. I can hard code a user name ie

```
:APP_USER like 'Betty Boop%'
```

How can I set an item to be read only based on the Access Control group that a user belongs to (ADMIN,EDIT,VIEW)

I know that there is a utility: `APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP`

but if I do something like READ ONLY PL/SQL Expression

```
APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP('VIEW')
```

It doesn't do anything.
It seems that `APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP` doesn't know that the groups created by Apex Access control are groups - I need to code something? Create a function? Create a group table?

I'm not understanding how to do this

thanks

Comment: these ADMIN/EDIT/VIEW are user groups defined in the user administration part of apex? In uppercase? You assigned the user(s) to these groups?

Answer (score 0):

To use `APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP` you need to create user group(s) as an workspace administrator first: `Administration->Manage Users and Groups->Groups->Create User Group`. 
Then you need to assign the group(s) to your application users: `Groups->User Group Assigments`. You should read [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35129/aadm_users.htm#BEJFDFDE) for more details.

And, after that you will be able to check an assignment of particular group to current application user with the `APEX_UTIL.CURRENT_USER_IN_GROUP` function.